# Why is my: MySQL connection not working?

Tags: c#, android

I want to make connection with MySQL, but it doesn't work!

The error that I get: Unhandled Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.

This is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "recepten" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.register);

    // Create your application here
    Button back = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.backToLog);
    Button maak = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.maakAccount);
    TextView naam = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.naam);
    TextView email = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.email);
    TextView ww = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.wachtwoord);
    TextView created = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.succes);

    back.Click += delegate { StartActivity(typeof(login1)); };

    maak.Click += delegate
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=db4free.net;Port=3306;database=foodproftaak;User Id=sanderenniek;Password=***;charset=utf8");

        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO register(naam, wachtwoord, email) VALUES(@naam, @wachtwoord, @email)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", naam);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wachtwoord", ww);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                created.Text = "You succesfully created an account";
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            created.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    };
}
```

Yours sincerely,

Sander

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  Some people cannot see them.  Also, you don't explain what "doesn't work".  Are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have not associated the connection with the command object. After you create your `MySqlCommand` object, assign the connection to it:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Alternately, you can pass the connection in when you create the `MySqlCommand` object:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO register(naam, wachtwoord, email) VALUES(@naam, @wachtwoord, @email)", con );
```